# How to get the current directory name and display it on the html page using node.js

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

Actually I have a path name in index.js file.whenever I select the directory, I'm able to see the current directory name in the node.js console screen.

Now, I want to display that directory name into the text box of `template.html` page. Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue?

In index.js, at this part I'm able to see the path name in the console:

```
app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
 var currentDir =  dir;
 var query = req.query.path || '';
 if (query) currentDir = path.join(dir, query);
 console.log("browsing ", currentDir);
```

My index.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var http = require('http');
var _ = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');

var program = require('commander');

function collect(val, memo) {
  if(val && val.indexOf('.') != 0) val = "." + val;
  memo.push(val);
  return memo;
}

program
  .option('-p, --port <port>', 'Port to run the file-browser. Default value is 8088')
  .option('-e, --exclude <exclude>', 'File extensions to exclude. To exclude multiple extension pass -e multiple times. e.g. ( -e .js -e .cs -e .swp) ', collect, [])
  .parse(process.argv);

var app = express();
var dir =  process.cwd();
app.use(express.static(dir)); //app public directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //module directory
var server = http.createServer(app);

if(!program.port) program.port = 8088;

server.listen(program.port);
console.log("Please open the link in your browser http://<YOUR-IP>:" + program.port);

app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
 var currentDir =  dir;
 var query = req.query.path || '';
 if (query) currentDir = path.join(dir, query);
 console.log("browsing ", currentDir);
 fs.readdir(currentDir, function (err, files) {
     if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      var data = [];
      files
      .filter(function (file) {
          return true;
      }).forEach(function (file) {
        try {
                //console.log("processing ", file);
                var isDirectory = fs.statSync(path.join(currentDir,file)).isDirectory();
                if (isDirectory) {
                  data.push({ Name : file, IsDirectory: true, Path : path.join(query, file)  });
                } else {
                  var ext = path.extname(file);
                  if(program.exclude && _.contains(program.exclude, ext)) {
                    console.log("excluding file ", file);
                    return;
                  }       
                  data.push({ Name : file, Ext : ext, IsDirectory: false, Path : path.join(query, file) });
                }

        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e); 
        }        

      });
      data = _.sortBy(data, function(f) { return f.Name });
      res.json(data);
  });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('lib/template.html'); 
});
```

My template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>File Browser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="panelDiv">

           <div class="panel-heading">
                   <button type="button" id="butDiv" >Browse</button>
                    <input type="text" name="location"/>
                   <span class="up">
                    <i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> Up
                   </span> 
           </div>
      <div id="showDiv" class="panel-body">
              <table class="linksholder">
              </table>
      </div>

  </div> 
    <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/datatable/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/app.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#butDiv").click(function(){
        $("#showDiv").toggle();

 });
});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js :

```
(function($){

        var extensionsMap = {
                      ".zip" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".gz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".bz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".xz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".rar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tgz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tbz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".7z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".mp3" : "fa-file-audio-o",         
                      ".cs" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".c++" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".cpp" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".js" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".xls" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".xlsx" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".png" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpeg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".gif" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".mpeg" : "fa-file-movie-o",         
                      ".pdf" : "fa-file-pdf-o",         
                      ".ppt" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".pptx" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".txt" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".log" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".doc" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                      ".docx" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                    };

  function getFileIcon(ext) {
    return ( ext && extensionsMap[ext.toLowerCase()]) || 'fa-file-o';
  }

   var currentPath = null;
   var options = {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
         "sScrollY":"250px",
        "fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
          if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
          var path = aData.Path;
          $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
             $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
              table.fnClearTable();
              table.fnAddData(data);
              currentPath = path;
            });
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        }, 
        "aoColumns": [
          { "sTitle": "", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
              } else {
                return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
              }
            }
          }
        ]
   };

  var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable(options);
  console.log(table);

  $.get('/files').then(function(data){
      table.fnClearTable();
      table.fnAddData(data);
  });

  $(".up").bind("click", function(e){
    if (!currentPath) return;
    var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var path =currentPath.substr(0, idx);
    $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnAddData(data);
        currentPath = path;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Current Browse Format :

[image]

Required Browse Format :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `template.html` is just a static html page but not a template, there is only one way to get data from the server - via an xhr request. You can add one more route to your `index.js`:

```
//...
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('lib/template.html'); 
});

app.get('/directory', function(req, res) {
  var currentDir =  dir;
  var query = req.query.path || '';
  if (query) currentDir = path.join(dir, query);
      var data = { directory: currentDir }
  res.json(data);
});
```

And then trigger one more xhr request (to this route) from your `app.js`:

```
$.get('/directory').then(function(data){        
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
});
```

Also, add it to `.up` event handler:

```
$(".up").bind("click", function(e){
    if (!currentPath) return;
    var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var path =currentPath.substr(0, idx);
    $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnAddData(data);
        currentPath = path;
    });
    $.get('/directory?path='+ path').then(function(data){        
            $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
    });
});
```

And modify `fnCreatedRow`:

```
"fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
    var path = aData.Path;
    $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
        $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
            table.fnClearTable();
            table.fnAddData(data);
            currentPath = path;
        });
        $.get('/directory?path='+ path').then(function(data){        
            $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
        });         
    e.preventDefault();
    });
},
```

You could also have added this data to `/files` route response.

One more way is to use templates. [Here](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html) you can read about template engines in express.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help.Actually I'm getting the slash in the textbox.But I want to display the current directory path into that textbox.Please help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: Here I'm able to get the value as slash.But not able to get the path of current directory.            $.get('/directory').then(function(data){        
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
});

Comment: can you please help me out.I'm unable to get the directory path in the response.In json,also I'm getting only slash as the output.I didn't get where I'm going wrong

Comment: I am busy right now, will be back in an hour or two and will help you.

Comment: Actually,I'm able to get the current path into the text box.

Comment: I've followed this url( https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/how-to-create-a-web-based-file-browser-using-nodejs-express-and-jquery-datatables/) . Here what I'm doing is,I'll go to one specific folder and give a "file-browser" command over there.Now I'm getting that specific folder path on to the text box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94301/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-gangigunta-divya).